# git журнал с номерами строк изменений

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

Нужно было вывести все свои изменения в гите.  В общем мне подошло `git log -p --author "nameauthor"`.

Но возникло пожелание чтобы к строчкам с добавлениями и удалениями был приписан номер их строки в файле, в который вносятся изменения. Как это сделать? (предлагали что-то с diff, но я не понял как).

Пример моего вывода:

```
commit 3e193d53e6440d6e131013386ef21a4923c71b5e
Author: ArturAhmetov <pumok@mail.ru>
Date:   Sat Oct 29 21:11:12 2016 +0300

    + formule

diff --git a/src/ColorCodingResistorForm.java b/src/ColorCodingResistorForm.java
index a219cd1..cc9a747 100644
--- a/src/ColorCodingResistorForm.java
+++ b/src/ColorCodingResistorForm.java
@@ -287,7 +287,28 @@ public class ColorCodingResistorForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     }                                           

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
-
+        try
+        {
+        double R1scale = Math.pow(10, 3*(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()));
+        double R2scale = Math.pow(10, 3*(jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()));
+        double U1scale = Math.pow(10, 3*(jComboBox3.getSelectedIndex()));
+        double Ascale = Math.pow(10, 3*(jComboBox4.getSelectedIndex()));
+                    
+        double R1=Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
+        double R2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
+        double U2=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
+        
+        double r1=R1*R1scale;
+        double r2 = R2*R2scale;
+        
+        double U1 = U2 * r2/(r1 + r2);
+         jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(U1*U1scale));  
+         jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf(U2/(r1+r2)*Ascale));
+        }
+        
+        catch (Exception e) {
+            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Проверьте правильность ввода параметров");
+        }
     }
```

Comment: ну так там есть номера строк. Но если хочется чего то большего, можно заменить diff на diff3 и настроить его. А там можно так http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#diff3-Hunks